# 555 timer delay circuit: resume after supply outage

Tags: 555

I have created a 555 delay circuit where **output** goes down after a delay of **T** minutes.

The 555 IC is in astable mode and is triggered automatically upon turning on the supply, Vcc.

After turning on the supply, when the output is still on (within T seconds) I turn off the supply for some time, after the supply resumes the timer output should be high for only remaining time.

In other words the circuit should *remember* the time it has elapsed before power outage.

Eg: Suppose `T = 5 minutes` . Ideally when the circuit is run without any interruption; the output goes down after **5 minutes**. In case I turn off the supply after **2 minutes**, and later turn supply on; **the timer should only have a delay of** **3 minutes**

What is the simplest and cheapest way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like a *delay-once, never again* design. How do you know when its OK to reset the 5 minute timer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the NE555 the IC I need, and if not, what do I replace it with?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486156/is-the-ne555-the-ic-i-need-and-if-not-what-do-i-replace-it-with)

Comment: The simplest and cheapest way to achieve this is **not** with a 555 timer.

Comment: @glen_geek when timer actually consumes the 5 minutes or through a reset button

Comment: It's the wrong solution to the problem. You are wasting your time using a 555 for that task. You would have to hold charge on a  capacitor with no leakage and a load of tricky circuitry to isolate it when off. Don't bother.

Comment: @Transistor  Yes I am planning to achieve this with an ATtiny MCU with battery backup. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219353/battery-backup-supply-switch-over-design